# Method "xxx" targeted by Callback constraint does not exist Symfony2

Tags: validation, symfony, callback, constraints

This method is inside my Entity class

```
public function validateStartDate(ExecutionContextInterface $context)
{
    if ($this->getEndDate() < $this->getStartDate()){
      $context->addViolationAt(
          'endDate',
          'End date cannnot be before Start date',
          array(),
          null
      );
    }

}
```

and im using a callback constraint on $startDate

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", name="start_date")
 * @Assert\Type("\DateTime")
 * @Assert\Callback(methods={"validateStartDate"})
 */
private $startDate;
```

I have the following imports

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ExecutionContextInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ExecutionContext;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
```

Using Symfony 2.5 with mysql.

The error i get when I submit my form is

> Method "validateStartDate" targeted by Callback constraint does not
>   exist

Any help in this regard will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Symfony 2.4, the Callback validator was [simplified](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html). You can use the Callback annotation on a method to tell Syfmony2 this is a custom function to execute on validate.

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
class Author
{
    /**
     * @Assert\Callback
     */
    public function validate(ExecutionContextInterface $context)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```